# dataframe index not equal to its copy

Tags: python, pandas

I've been down a long rabbit hole trying to reproduce a problem I'm seeing with a dataframe of length approximately 3.5 million.  The question boils down to:

#### Question

Can someone produce an example of this happening:

```
df.index.is_unique

True
```

And

```
df.index.copy().is_unique

False
```

I didn't think this should be possible, but I assure you that I'm seeing it.  I just can't reduce it to something I can post.

Pandas `0.18.1`
Python `2.7`

Comment: What is the output of `(df.index == df.index.copy()).all())`?

Comment: When I get back home, I'll tell you